# Ada-style Range Types in D

Tags: d, compile-time, compile-time-constant, range-types

After having read [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/ada-style-ranged-types-in-c/201001318?pgno=1) interesting article about Ada and C++ and knowing of D's support for CTFE and constant-parameter specialization of functions I wonder if Ada-Style Range types could be more easily/efficiently implemented in D than in C++. Has anybody perhaps already written such a library?

If such ranges could be implemented efficiently and developer-friendly in D it could be used as a promotor for establishing D in sectors with demands on determinism and type- and memory-safety (were D already shines) such as in avionics and automotive. D would thereby gain more developer-interest and stronger financial support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote some little code that does min and max of integers with overflow check:

http://arsdnet.net/dcode/ranged.d

This was just a proof of concept though, I doubt it will perform very well, but might if inlined.

Comment: Thanks Adam - I remember I saw it somewhere! :) This is exactly the code I had in mind. :)

Comment: Can this be extended to floating point types (w/ or w/o assembly assistance)?

Comment: Yeah, it should be possible. I don't know if there's a float overflow flag like the asm checks here, but we could do something like if result < max(addends) where both are positive, we know it overflowed. The range check itself would work, since that's just a > comparison.... I changed the file (refresh the link) to do static if on the asm, so now it should work on float on simple cases at least.

Comment: Great! I'll experiment with it.

Comment: Shouldn't you do the check `if(_payload < min) goto overflow;` in the else clause? Or are there two kinds of checks? And what does `return q` mean? I see no definition/declaration of the symbol `q`. I guess we need to check for Infinity or Max-Float instead, right?

Comment: q{ } is actually a string literal. That helper function returns a string that is pasted into the individual functions below with the mixin(...) lines. It is similar to a text macro the way I did it here. The reason is to ensure the overflow flag isn't changed by a function call.

Comment: The other thing there is there's two kinds of checks: the overflow check and the bounds check. Overflow check is only implemented for integers and is the top part, then below it is the bounds check. It does both because with overflow, ((x + 1) < x) might be true. Like on a single byte, 255 + 1 = 0 because it wraps around. So just checking if(result > max) won't necessarily work. But we can't just check overflow either because the limits could be anything. If it is max == 10, 9 + 5 won't wrap around, but 14 > 10 so it is still out of range.

Comment: I believe you simply can't do this as there's no guarantee that the compiler will set the flags in the generated code, or that intervening code won't corrupt the flags, as the comment about += 1 not setting the carry flag points out. Consider also what happens in the admittedly undemonstrated hypothetical extreme case where constants are passed and the compiler simply reduces the expression at compile-time even.

Comment: I wrote some very similar, but far less general, code and wrote the arithmetic operations right in the asm next to an x86 `SETcc` instruction to return a bool second result, but of course a conditional branch could have been used. I used GDC extended asm which is far more powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Having scalar (bounded) variable is easily done in D as a template, and in fact I remember I saw the code that someone already did it. Unfortunately I do not remember where I saw it. This said, there is IMHO no need for this to become part of the language, but rather part of the standard library.

(**Edit:** Adam reminded me of the code: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/ranged.d )

Ranges are more wider concept nicely explained in Andrei's article - http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357&rll=1 .
This type of ranges are now a core concept of D. D's slice is an implementation of the most powerful range - *RandomAccessRange*.

Example:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;

void main()
{
    int[] values = [ 1, 20, 7, 11 ]; // values is a RandomAcessRange
    writeln(filter!(value => value > 10)(values));
}
```

Good reads:

1. http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ranges.html
2. http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/component-programming-in-d/240008321
3. http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html

Comment: not that type of range but a bounded (scalar) variable (like a real with a min and max)